# Rails 4 with Rolify - assigning scoped roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles, rolify

I'm trying to figure out how to assign scoped roles in my Rails 4 app.

I have models for User, Role and Organisation.

The user table has all the users. The roles table has the CRUD for creating roles (i.e. guest, student etc). The organisation table lists all the organisations and all roles will be assigned to users with an organisation scope.

My models are:

User

```
rolify strict: true # strict means you get true only on a role that you manually add
attr_accessor :current_role
```

Role

```
scopify
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: "users_roles"
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true
```

Organisation

```
resourcify
```

I made a controller called assign_roles_controller.rb.

It has:

```
def index
    @roles = Role.all 
    @users = User.all
end


  def create
    user = User.find(params[:users])
    role = Role.find(params[:roles])
    organisation = Organisation.first # once I get this working, I'll find the relevant organisation that the user is related to)

    user.add_role role.name, organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to action: :index
  end
```

In my assign roles index, I am trying:

```
<%= form_tag(url: '/assign_roles', method: :post ) do |f| %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
    <%= select_tag "users", options_from_collection_for_select(@users, "id", "formal_name"), { class: "chosen-select form-control" } %>
    </div>

<!-- # roles -->

  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
    <%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, "id", "name"), :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>
    </div>
</div>
<%= submit_tag(value = "Save changes") %>
<% end %>
```

When I try all of this, I expect to be able to check if the user has been assigned a role, scoped to an organisation.

Following the example in the rolify docs, I try:

```
u.has_role? :asdf, Organisation.first
```

I get an error that says:

```
  Organisation Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "organisations".* FROM "organisations"  ORDER BY "organisations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `has_role?' for #<User:0x007fee2b4a1098>
Did you mean?  has_attribute?
```

I can see from the console, that the roles table has been updated by the assign roles form. I'm concerned  that this is incorrect, because the role should be available for assignment to all organisations - but each time it is assigned, the user that is given the role should have that role scoped to the relevant organisation. This table entry doesnt look right because now it is updated with organisation id of 1.

```
Role.last
  Role Load (4.9ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles"  ORDER BY "roles"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Role id: 9, name: "asdf", resource_id: 1, resource_type: "Organisation", created_at: "2016-08-15 00:03:25", updated_at: "2016-08-15 00:03:25", enduring?: false, expiry_date: nil, display_name: nil>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

I'm wondering if I need to make a new table for the AppRoles (being the roles that I want to create for use in the app). Then the Roles table that I currently have can be used to hold instances of each role created for a user and assigned with an organisation scope. Is this approach sensible?

Comment: I made an additional table called 'MasterRoles'. I use that table to create the role names that are available to the app. I then use the Roles table to hold each instance of each role that is assigned to a user. I can't find any examples of this in the rolify documents.  I now have an additional controller called AssignRoles, which allows admins to assign scoped roles (where the role is defined in the MasterRoles table) and once assigned, is added to the Role table. If anyone has figured out how to manage scoped roles, I'd love some help.